# Codeigniter 3 flashdata is always appearing

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter 3, and flashdata to show an error message to the user when inserting an invalid username or password.

The problem is that the message is always showing even when the page was just opened and no password or username was inserted.

EDIT:
The comparison and the authentication are right but when i open the page it still appear even when no action was taken.

this is the form

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?>
```

and this is the controller

```
public function authentication(){

    //post user unput
    $empNum=$this->input->post('employeeNum');
    $pwd=$this->input->post('password');

    $user=$this->empNumAuth($empNum, $pwd);

    if($user) {

        if($user['PrivilegeLevel']==='1'){

            $this->session->set_userdata($user);
            redirect('AdminDashboard/view');

        }
        else if($user['PrivilegeLevel']=='2') { 
            
            $this->session->set_userdata($user);
            redirect('UserDashboard/view');
        }

    }

    else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','الرقم الوظيفي او رمز الدخول خاطئ');
        redirect('Login/LoginPage');
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: i did not understand what's the problem

Comment: if *flashdata is always appearing*, you need to check why your `if($user)` never is true

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the flashdata is set whenever the authentication fails( $this->empNumAuth() returns false). So if the path **/authentication** gets called, and no password or username is entered, it passes blank values to the empNumAuth() function, which will definitely return a false value(since blank values were passed, so the authentication will fail). Otherwise, if you feel the flashdata should not be shown, and you are sure valid credentials were submitted, then the problem lies within the empNumAuth() function, start checking from there.

BONUS:
If you are echoing the flashdata message within an error/success div, it will always display, with no text on it. That is, suppose you have an error div formatted with a red background, when you echo the flashdata directly as you did, the error div will be displayed but with blank text. The best way is to check if the flashdata is set before echoing it. See the example below. (I have used default Bootstrap error alert div)

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg'){?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?> 
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The above code checks if the flashdata is set which will prevent the flashdata div from being displayed always.

Answer (score 0):

Use the above code in view file...

```
<?php
 if($this->session->flashdata('msg')
  {
?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?> 
   </div>
<?php 
  } 
?>
```

Comment: If it's possible please explain why your code should be used and how it works. Just giving a piece of code and saying "use it" does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use PHP 8+? If so, your problem might be caused by your CodeIgniter version. I assume you used the older version of the framework and used PHP 8+. This CodeIgniter [changelog page](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#bug-fixes-for-3-1-12) contains information about the *Session flashdata* bug in PHP 8 before version 3.1.12. So, you could solve your problem by upgrading your CodeIgniter version to 3.1.12 or the newest one.